# Java BigInteger(byte[] val)

Tags: java, arrays, biginteger

I am trying to understand how does the java.math.BigInteger.BigInteger(byte[] val) constructor work.

For example when I create a BigInteger instance from the byte array [1, 0], the corresponding string it creates is 256. Surely, the binary string 10 corresponds to value 2 in base 10. How does it convert it from 10 to 256? What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each byte in the array represents 8 bits, so `[1, 0]` is equivalent to `1 * 2^(8 * 1) + 0 * 2^(8 * 0)`, or, in binary: `00000001 00000000`.

Beware that the BigInteger (byte[]) constructor also uses [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), so it's not just a matter of adding the unsigned numbers: the most significant bit will affect the sign.

Answer (score 4):

It's effectively working in base-256, not base-2.  So each position in the input array is worth 256 times more than the next position.

Pseudo-code:

```
x = 0;
for (i = 0; i < val.length - 1; i++) {
    x = (x*256) + val[i];
}
```

Comment: What? Wouldn't that mean `10` is worth `512` then?

Comment: @Johan No, "10" means 1*256 + 0 then.

Comment: @Johan: The last position is in units of 1.  The second-to-last element is in units of 256.  The third-to-last element is in units of 256*256.  etc.